# How to use timer for update time after 5 min in registry

Tags: c#

How to use timer for update time after 5 min in registry. My registry file in `"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"` file. Its run only first time when computer start.I want to update time in registry after 5 min automatically.

Comment: So do u want to update data for every minutes or you have to store that time at that registry for every 5 minutes

Comment: rectify me if I am wrong, you know the path and you want to create a registry key inside the path what you mentioned above? 

Now if I am not wrong then you can do it by changing the permissions of the registry folders and subfolders on the specific path and you can overwrite the key value after each 5 minutes according to your timer value.

Create a C# timer, set its Interval to 300000(5 * 60 * 1000), handle its Tick event, and use the Registry class to allow permission and again to disable the allow Permission.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `RunOnce` key instead, which will only run once.

To answer the question: Make a timer, set its `Interval` to `5 * 60 * 1000` milliseconds, handle its `Tick` event, and use the `Registry` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.Timers.Timer t=new Timer();
    t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);
    t.interval = 5 * 60 * 1000;
    t.Start();

    void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
```

Comment: Do not recommend `System.Timers.Timer` since it hides errors (all unhandled exceptions will silently be ignored). `System.Threading.Timer` ftw.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. can you please provide some links associated with its pitfalls ?

Comment: From MSDN: `In the .NET Framework version 2.0 and earlier, the Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the Elapsed event. This behavior is subject to change in future releases of the .NET Framework`. It does not say if it have been changed yet or not.

Comment: Thanks again sir. Kindly refer the link

Answer (score 0):

You could user `Timer` control of C# and sets its interval to 300000. It assumes the value in milliseconds.